# sequelize (Relations / Associations) subQuery

Tags: sequelize.js

Sequelize.js
One-To-Many associations

```
var City = sequelize.define('city', { countryCode: Sequelize.STRING });
var Country = sequelize.define('country', { isoCode: Sequelize.STRING });

// Here we can connect countries and cities base on country code
Country.hasMany(City, {foreignKey: 'countryCode', sourceKey: 'isoCode'});
City.belongsTo(Country, {foreignKey: 'countryCode', targetKey: 'isoCode'});
```

[Country] & [City] in DB, like that:

```
- Country-001
    * City-001-1
    * City-001-2
    * City-001-3
- Country-002
    * City-002-1
    * City-002-2
    * City-002-3
- Country-003
    no city
- Country-004
    * City-004-1
    * City-004-2
    * City-004-3
...
- Country-100
    * City-100-1
    * City-100-2
    * City-100-3
```

I want Query [Country] that exist [City], with offset & limit, use ORM, not sql, like that:

```
Country.findAll({
    where: {},
    include: [],
    offset: 0,
    limit: 10
});
```

**I don't known how to do it ?**

I tried some way, they are not work well.
This way is not correct, it will return 9 [Country] not 10, [Country-003] really not in result, But limit is not correct.

```
Country.findAll({
    where: {},
    include: [mode: City, require: true],
    offset: 0,
    limit: 10
});
```

Comment: add require false and try

Comment: But, I don't want [Country] has no [City] be returned in result.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, putting `require: true` means that if a `Country` doesn't have any `City` objects associated with it, then it won't be returned as part of the query.

Also, the structure of your query depends on what you're trying to limit.

If you want to get back only 10 `Country` records in total, with any number of `City` objects associate with each one:

```
Country.findAll({
  include: [{
    model: City,
    require: true,
  }],
  limit: 10
});
```

If you want to get back all `Country` objects, but only up to 10 `City` objects associated with each one:

```
Country.findAll({
  include: [{
    model: City,
    require: true,
    limit: 10
  }],
});
```

As mentioned previously, you can also drop `required: true` to lift the restriction that a `Country` has to have any `City` objects associated to be in the results.

Comment: [County] in results will be 9,not 10.